# What is the right/best verb to use for tapping a contactless smart card?

Tags: single-word-requests

**What is the right or best verb for expressing that we are tapping a [contactless smart card](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Contactless_smart_card&oldid=1131441468)?**

It is my understanding that the best choice of verb in English is "to tap", even though only physical proximity and no actual physical contact is necessary.

For some fun trivia, people at Princeton University use the verb "to prox" ("Can you prox me in?"). This Princeton-specific slang is potentially related to the lesser-used expression "proximity card".

While we're at it: **What's the best way of saying "smart card"?**

Comment: [Laŭ prikomputila terminokolekto "Komputeko"](https://komputeko.net/#smart%20card) la esprimo por "smart card" estas «inteligenta memorkarto», sed tiu ŝajnas al mi esti tro-laŭvorta traduko el la angla.

Comment: En tiu kazo, mi pensas ke oni anstataŭe devus uzi simple la vorton "karto".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la *inteligenta* karto oni povas uzi simple `karto`. Se bezonatas klarigi pri kia karto temas, adjektivo(j) tion faras: identiga, magneta, senkontakta, strikoda, ktp.

Ago por senkontaktaj karto povus esti `(al)proksimigi`, `apogi`, `prezenti` (la [unua signifo en PIV](https://vortaro.net/#prezenti_kd) estas *Meti ion antaŭ iu, por ke tiu ĝin prenu, vidu aŭ juĝu*. La elekto de la verbo dependas de la tipo de senkontakta karto.

Comment: "*juĝu*. La elekto" -> "*juĝu*). La elekto"

Comment: Konsiderante vian respondon, mi ŝatas la vortgrupon `uzi la karton` por ĝenerala uzo kaj la vortgrupon `proksimigi la karton` por esti pli specifa.

Answer (score 2):

First I would avoid using words like intelligent or smart. These can be considered marketing words to set such cards apart from those with a magnet stripe. There is nothing smart in them.

According to Komputeko contactless payment is the obvious [*senkontakta pagado*](https://komputeko.net/#contactless%20payment). Thereby a card could be *karto por senkontakta pagado* or shorter *pagokarto* (also found in Komputeko) or just *karto*.

When it comes to using a card, I agree that the general term is *uzi*. The particular action of bringing the card near the reader can be described with

- [*prezenti*](https://vortaro.net/#prezenti_kd): there is an example at the definition 1: *prezenti al la komitato rajtigan leteron*.
- [*montri*](https://vortaro.net/#montri_kd): there is an example at the definition 1: *montri sian langon al la kuracisto*.

Based on those I would say *prezenti/montri pagokarton al la legilo por senkontakta pagado* and shortering it to *prezenti/montri la karton*.

Comment: I agree that the English term "smart card" is odd.